# Sizing <option> independently from <select>

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, cross-browser

We have a site with a large numerical select element which is currently set up as a 'spinner' wheel of sorts but we need to change it over to a standard `<select><option>` type input instead. The problem is that it looks like Chrome and new versions of Safari now show the drop down options as the same font size as the select element, where as Firefox shows the dropdown in the browser-native font size, which we prefer.

This seems like a strange behavior on behalf of Chrome / Safari because they don't allow other styles to carry over to  from  (font, color, etc).

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5om8cp77/6/) to demonstrate, you can try it in different browsers to see the different outputs.

We really want to stick with native  rather than designing something custom to maintain the native mobile select interfaces of iOS Safari, Android Chrome, etc.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

```css
.select-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.selectClass {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
    font-size: 96px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.selectClass option {
    font-size: 16px !important;
}

.selectClass .option-5 {
    font-size: 16px !important;
}
```

```html
<div class='select-wrapper'>
<select class="selectClass">
  <option value="">Option 1</option>
  <option value="">Option 2</option>
  <option value="">Option 3</option>
  <option value="">Option 4</option>
  <option class='option-5' value="">Option 5</option>
  <option value="">Option 6</option>
  <option value="">Option 7</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: FYI: If you add `font-family: serif` to `selectClass`, you'll see even _more_ inconsistencies. On macOS Chrome, the font-size carries over to the options, but the font-family does not!

Comment: native select box have different display from different browser, but if you want to make it look the same in all browser better check https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/

Comment: You can apply only very limited set of CSS to `select`'s `option`. So if you want really customizable solution you'd better 1) Write your own block with `position: absolute` or 2) use some JavaScript components to achieve dropdown funtionality.

Comment: Really frustrating how they go about handling these, really. I'm not upset that you can't style insomuch upset that some styles are applied and some aren't and there is NO independent control of styles between `option` and `select` - I'm doing a floor selector for a 45-story building - I want the selected floor to be a large number on-screen, but I sure as hell don't need the drop-down to be the same huge numbers... and I wanted to do that while maintaining native UI on mobile.
"TOO BAD" _-Chrome/Safari_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an interesting problem and one that I've come across myself but as far as I know there is now way to achieve this. Read this [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/dropdown-default-styling/#article-header-id-3) article for a more complete treatment.

Several browsers lock down certain components and don't expose options to modify their styling without some serious wizardry. Another similar but different example is a [checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148499/how-to-style-checkbox-using-css), while you can customize checkboxes doing so is non-trivial.

I'd suggest either revisiting your design as the author of CSS Tricks suggests or you could go with a already made solution such as [Select2 Plugin](https://select2.github.io/), or [Selectize](http://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/), or you could make one from scratch using these as a reference.

Comment: Thanks jeanpier_re, looks like custom it is. I'll take a look at these, might save me some time on mobile.